# Is it possible to learn a neural networks for a constant target?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, optimization

I saw a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10147) where they learn L based on the following cost function:

$$(D_1L(q(k-1), q(k)) + D_2L(q(k),q(k+1)))² = 0$$

Here $D$ is the derivative with respect to ith argument of L. This can be obtained via automatic differentiation and it is fully compatible with backpropagation. So the target is always zero independently of the input of L but how does the optimization method knows the real values of L for a given input? I mean as long as the cost function is satisfied with a zero value the model is learning but it can be learning wrong values for L. For instance, if the real value of $D_1L(q(k-1), q(k))$ is 10 then the real value of $D_2L(q(k),q(k+1))$ has to be -10. However the neural network may be learning wrong values for L as long as they are symmetric, for example -3 and 3. This is an ill posed problem due to the infinite possible solutions. Am I missing something or the method in that paper simply doesn't make any sense? Is it possible to learn a neural network in regression task with constant target?

Edit: The goal is not to predict always that value. The goal is to learn L by predicting always zero (see the cost function). The question here is in order to learn L in such a way that it respects the cost function, there are infinite possible solutions, for instance if $D1L(q(k−1),q(k))$ = x then D2L(q(k),q(k+1))=-x and its sum gives 0 respecting the cost function. But as you can see x can assume any value as long as the cost function is respected, when in reality the goal is to learn a specific L. But the optimization doesn't know a priori value for L so I guess it should just assume a random value for x. In the paper they don't mention the ill posedness of the problem, either they solved it or not. I would like to know if what I'm thinking makes sense or if I'm just missing something.

Comment: There must be some kind of constraint or other information imposed on the network. But without a citation to the paper, it's impossible to know what these might be.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask the same question. You can edit the question to make it more clear, or place a bounty on it to draw attention (once you have enough reputation).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. The paper is available here https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10147

Comment: The paper citation would be a good thing to edit into the body of the question you asked yesterday.

Comment: I am confused. If the target value is constant, then always predict that value. (You get the right answer every time!) What is happening beyond this?

Comment: @Dave I've merged in the comments from the duplicate thread. I assume that this is nontrivial because there are constraints on $L$ and $q$ which result in an interesting network. Presumably this is outlined in he paper, but I haven't read it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Dave I added an edit to que question to better explain the problem itself.

Comment: @Sycorax The paper just mentions the cost function that I outlined and says it learns L based on that. No other contraint is included as far as I understood the paper. I'm doing a very similar approach right now and experimentally I can verify my assumptions.

Comment: What is $L$ and what is $q$? Presumably they aren't just any functions because the paper abstract talks about lattices a lot.

Comment: @Sycorax  The equation is the discrete euler lagrange equation. The goal is to learn L (Lagrangian) in such a way that it respects the cost function which relates energy conservation for long time simulation according with discrete mechanics theory. Q is the input of the dataset, it is a discrete trajectory. For instance, for a system like a pendulum it can be the angle of the mass.

Comment: You're using the same $L$ in both summands, so it's not the case that the second term in the sum is a "free" parameter that can be set to the negative of the first term in the sum. In other words, you're searching for an $L$ s.t. $D_1 L = -D_2 L$. I don't think this is trivial, because there must be some physical reason that $L$ is not a constant function at 0 (or any other trivial solution).

Comment: L is not constant at all. Both summands depend on different inputs. What has to be constant and equal to zero is the sum of the gradients (cost function) for every 3 points (input data) in the trajectory.

Comment: Based on the description in this post, I see no reason that $L(x,y)=0$ is excluded as a solution. Finding the answer to your question hinges on understanding why this is not a valid solution. I suspect it has to do with the physical nature of this problem. This is what I mean by a "constraint" or "other information."

Comment: Exactly L has to follow a specific value defined by the laws of physics and not a set of infinite solutions.

Comment: The equation quoted in the question is not the cost function used in the paper. Instead, the cost is given as $F(\psi)$, immediately after eq. 9. In other words, the paper uses MSE as its loss.

Comment: Yes where the forward is defined by the equation above. The MSE is used to compare the value predicted by the forward equation with an constant which in this case is zero. In reality the loss is that equation squared. I just wrote it in a different way.